# IE: word-wrap and word-break issue in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

The following issue is only observed in IE browsers.

Please find below the link of demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/reoh7j74/142/

Click on "Source" toolbar item and paste the following code in the textarea of CKEditor:

```
<div style="left:0; text-align: center; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-word">abc</div>
```

Then again click on Source button to switch to HTML View and then move to Code View, you will find the following code:

```
<div style="left: 0px; text-align: center; -ms-word-wrap: break-word;">abc</div>
```

Word-break is getting removed from the  tag and word-wrap is converted into ms-word-wrap. I want to keep all the attributes as it is in this scenario. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: It doesn't change anything for me. Have you modified your fiddle? The way to go about this is to use `extraAllowedContent`, which I notice you have.

Comment: It only does it when using IE, very annoying behaviour!

Comment: @James - May be you haven't tried this jsfiddle in IE. This behaviour is only getting occurred in IE browsers.